# AWS ec2 ubuntu downgrade php7.2 to 7.0

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I have not found a good explanation on how I can downgrade PHP 7.2 to PHP 7.0 on the Ubuntu distribution in AWS EC2.

I've tried: `sudo apt-get install php7.0` and `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` and then the previous command. While it looks like PHP 7.0 has downloaded,

I attempt to do: `sudo a2dismod 7.2` and `sudo a2enmod 7.0`
dismod is successful, while enmod on 7.0 throws: `ERROR: Module php7.0 does not exist!`

Comment: PHP 7.0 was discontinued over a year ago. https://www.php.net/eol.php

Comment: so? That would prevent me from installing it ? @ceejayoz

Comment: Yes. You're using `ondrej/php`. https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/ "Don't ask for end-of-life PHP versions or Ubuntu release, they won't be provided."

Comment: @ceejayoz is there another repo we can pull from ?

Comment: You should not be using a no longer supported version of PHP. It's dangerous.